# Making a rowwise selection based on a specific column condition on a dataframe

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I am a little perplex based on a specific data manipulation I want to perform.
I want to look for animals with a specific **Id** repeated over time **t** where they can be treated (variable *Treat==1*) or not (*Treat==0*).
The dataframe **bd** I have is the following example:

```
bd =data.frame(t=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6), #6 measurement periods for the individuals  
                 Id= rep(1:18, each=6, length.out=18), #3 individuals repeated over time
                 Treat=c(0,0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) # variable indicating if the animal was treated for this period of time yes if 1 and no if 0               
) # I want to keep rows of the Id starting from Treat==1.
```

In the end I want to keep :for individual 1 the rows starting where *Treat=="1"* (ie row of Id=1 and t from t=3 to t=6, for Id=2, the rows with t=5 and t=6 and no row for Id=3 because *Treat==0*.

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `Treat` means a treatment was applied on that time `t`, and you wish to get only that data which was after each animal was treated. So for each `Id`, you want the row with `Treat=1`, and also every row after (where Treat=0`).

There are several ways to do it. I will show two.

---

One is to create a new column `status` which is 1 on the treatment day, and also 1 on every day thereafter. You can the easily filter by `status = 1`. Luckily tidyverse has a function for this called `cummax` (max of all rows up to that one) that we can use.

```r
library(tidyverse)

result = bd %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(status = cummax(Treat)) %>%
  filter(status == 1)

result

      t    Id Treat status
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     3     1     1      1
2     4     1     0      1
3     5     1     0      1
4     6     1     0      1
5     5     2     1      1
6     6     2     0      1
```

---

The second is more correct but also more complicated. You create a new column called `t_treatment`, that shows what day the animal was treated. This will be replicated along the entire series, but that's okay. Then you filter on `t >= t_treatment`. This will work even if `Treat` is not something where max works well (like a `factor` or string). It's also more extensible if you later need to do more complex things with multiple treatments (eg. rows after first two treatments within a week of each other).

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Get treatment dates
treatments = bd %>% 
  filter(Treat == 1) %>%
  mutate(t_treatment = t) %>%
  select(Id, t_treatment)

# Perform a join back to the original data and filter
result = bd %>% 
  merge(treatments) %>%
  filter(t >= t_treatment)

result

  Id t Treat t_treatment
1  1 3     1           3
2  1 4     0           3
3  1 5     0           3
4  1 6     0           3
5  2 5     1           5
6  2 6     0           5
```